# Use coffeescript for Chrome Content Script?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, coffeescript

I've previously used coffeescript for Chrome extensions, but only for background pages and popup pages - each of which can launch coffeescript via loading coffee-script.js and my own .coffee file from `<script>` tags.

However this time I'd like to make a content script - per the chrome docs, content scripts are specified not via a .html page, but via the manifest.json directly.

```
"content_scripts": [
   {
       "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
        "css": ["mystyles.css"],
        "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
   }
],
```

Since I don't have a .html file, I can't use a `<script type="text/coffeescript">` tag. Is there a way to launch a .coffee file from a .js file directly?

Or is my only option to pre-compile the .coffee file?

Answer (score 2):

The convention for apps is to [compile to Javascript and publish that](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html), so your app doesn't depend on Coffeescript. This makes sense for Chrome extensions too. See https://github.com/hickford/nutake for an example

Answer (score 1):

You can manually launch scripts using coffeescript.js

I didn't look further but I see compile / eval / load and run functions on the CoffeeScript global object.